# xsl to remove comments from specific nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a big XML file the setup my application. There are a lot of comments for each configuration. I want to use a xsl to remove some comment according to the node.

```
<!-- if you need to use storage -->
<Storage>
    <!-- Oracle configuration
    <StorageDb database="OracleService"></StorageDb>
    -->
    <!-- SqlServer configuration
    <StorageDb database="SqlService"></StorageDb>
    -->
</Storage>
```

When I run my xsl i want to remove just the comments from Oracle configuration, so my result would be:

```
<!-- if you need to use storage -->
<Storage>
    <StorageDb database="OracleService"></StorageDb>

    <!-- SqlServer configuration
    <StorageDb database="SqlService"></StorageDb>
    -->
</Storage>
```

Any idea how I would make it?

Comment: Do you mean 'uncomment' some nodes? In other words: extract nodes from comments.

Comment: Why do you want to use XSL for this? If there is a way to achieve such a transformation - it will be more or less ugly hack in XSL. I would propose simple search & replace for solving this problem.

Comment: @DRCB: he said "according to some nodes," so maybe he wants to use XSLT to match on certain nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Storage" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-after(.,'Oracle configuration')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but remember that d-o-e will only work in limited circumstances (e.g. when the XSLT processor has control of serialization) and is not required to be honored at all.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right, what you ask is not removing comment nodes but analyze them and transform them to elements. You can do that with XSLT 2.0 and regex capabilities, but I don't think it's a good idea (not really robust).

An XSLT can help you anyway, but you first have to build a squelet for your configuration file. Let's imagine something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <Storage/>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Your XSLT could look like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="service" select="'OracleService'"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Storage">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <StorageDb database="{$service}"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The default behavior selects the value `OracleService` for the `service` parameter. It's possible to override this behavior by passing another value to the XSLT for this parameter.

Default result is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <Storage><StorageDb database="OracleService"/></Storage>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: I do have the node already in the XML file, but commented. I need to uncomment that node. sorry, is it clear?

Comment: Yes, I understood that you have the comments in the XML, I just wanted to point out that a more robust alternative to the comment analysys could be an XSLT file with input parameters to build your configuration file.

Comment: "not removing comment nodes but analyze them and transform them to XML nodes" - I think you mean "transform them to elements"? They are already XML nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Saxon as your XSLT processor, then a robust way to do this (by which I mean, a method that doesn't rely on `disable-output-escaping`) would be to use `saxon:parse()` on the content of each comment node, after stripping out unwanted text. The result of `saxon:parse()` is an XML node, which can be output to the result document in the normal way.

E.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(substring-after(., 'configuration'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

For more discussion, see [XSLT parse text node as XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041202/xslt-parse-text-node-as-xml)

Comment: My understanding is that xith `saxon:parse()` function, you have to provide a string representing a valid XML document (see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/parse.xml). And so, to use this function on the comment nodes, you first have to perform an action on the text value (`substring`, `replace`...).

Comment: @VincentBiragnet: You're quite right... I assumed, without checking, that `parse()` could parse a document fragment. I'll edit my answer accordingly.