# XSL - FOP Replace html tag from CDATA Node

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, apply-templates

While generating the xsl-fo, I'm trying  to replace the html tags inside a CDATA node, but the template is not applying. I can see that if I remove the cdata from the node, then is applying fine.

How can I do to work keeping CDATA inside the node, because is necessary.

An example of the XML is:

```
<parentElement>
<Element1>
    <![CDATA[<strong>bold text here</strong> bla bla bla]]>
</Element1>
</parentElement>
```

The code in the fo is like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/parentElement/Element1" />
```

And the template for replacing the "bold" tags is:

```
<xsl:template match="strong">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:inline>  
</xsl:template>
```

Im really stuck with this, any help wourl be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Read also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512924/3016153

Comment: Hope it was easier...

Comment: It is (relatively) easy if you can use XSLT 3.0. Otherwise it's not easy, because your data provider did not make it easy.