# Parse the XML Elements inside the CData Using XSLT and Print to HTML

Tags: xslt

Input xml `is`

```
<getArtifactContentResponse>
<return>
<![CDATA[
<metadata>
<overview>       
<name>scannapp</name>
<developerId>developer702</developerId>
<stateId>2</stateId>
<serverURL>abc.com</serverURL>
<id>cspapp1103</id>
<description>scann doc</description>
<hostingTypeId>1</hostingTypeId>       
</overview>
</metadata>
  ]]>
  </return>
</getArtifactContentResponse>
```

Below is the stylesheet which I have developed. I am able to retrieve the XML inside Cdata but not able to fetch the elements value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h1>Company Details</h1>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <th>name</th>
                  <th>developerId</th>
                  <th>Id</th>
               </tr>table

               <xsl:variable name ="data" select="//getArtifactContentResponse/return/node()" />
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$data/metadata/overview/name" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>


                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$data/metadata/overview/developerId" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$data/metadata/overview/Id" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>

            </table>

         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output coming as

```
<html><body><h1>Company Details</h1><table border="1"><tr><th>name</th><th>developerId</th><th>serverURL</th></tr>table


                  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Expected output

```
<html><body><h1>Company Details</h1><table border="1"><tr><th>name</th><th>developerId</th><th>serverURL</th></tr>table


                  <tr><td>scannapp</td><td>developer702</td><td>cspapp1103</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

I want to take the value name,developerId,Id and print to HtML. How to do that Please help me. Using XSLT version1.0.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? You need an extension function that can parse a string with XML into nodes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Which function do you have in mind?

Comment: @user3016153, depending on the XSLT processor there are existing solutions or it is easy to implement one, for instance with Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` you can use an extension function or object that them makes use of an `XPathDocument` to parse the XML. With Microsoft's MSXML you can use an extension function implemented in JScript that simply needs to create e.g. `function parseXml(string) { var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0'); doc.loadXML(string); return doc; }`.

Comment: I tried but getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.parse([ExpressionContext,]

Comment: In my commented I made suggestions on how to implement an extension function for Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform` XSLT processor and for Microsoft's MSXML XSLT processor. As all that is processor dependent it will not work with other processors. I asked you in the first comment to tell us which XSLT processor you use. If you use Java then I would suggest to use a version of Saxon having an extension function to parse XML into nodes, like http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT parse text node as XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041202/xslt-parse-text-node-as-xml)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no way to parse CDATA **as XML**.

Using an extension function to parse the section **as text** would be nice, but not really necessary. Here's an example that extracts the three items you're after:

```
...
<xsl:variable name ="cdata" select="/getArtifactContentResponse/return" />

<name>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($cdata, '&lt;name&gt;'), '&lt;/name&gt;')"/>
</name>

<developerId>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($cdata, '&lt;developerId&gt;'), '&lt;/developerId&gt;')"/>
</developerId>

<id>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($cdata, '&lt;id&gt;'), '&lt;/id&gt;')"/>
</id>
...
```

Comment: The code is working fine.and I am getting expected result. Thanks a lot .. Is there any alternative way, as I dont want to use substring function.

Comment: I believe the substring function provides the shortest path to your expected output. Why wouldn't you want to use it?